# Polyhedral surface with infinitely many triangulations with same combinatorics

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics, polyhedra, discrete-geometry, triangulation

Is there an example of a polyhedral surface that has infinitely many triangulations with the same combinatorics?

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question. A polyhedral surface has, by the usual definition, a finite number of vertices, which cannot support an infinite number of triangulations.

Comment: But can a given polyhedral surface with finitely many vertices not have a triangulation with infinitely many vertices?
Or you could have a periodic and/or unbounded polyhedral surface...?

Comment: Oh, I see. Then you are using the word "triangulation" in a sense not widely shared. The answer is certainly *Yes* then. Because you could add a vertex in the interior of every triangle, and move them around a bit.